# Diffing web assets

Tags: webserver, diff, local

Is there a utility that can do a diff between a set of files on the web and a set of files on the user's local hard drive?

For example, if I execute:

```
urldiff http://www.website.com c:\src
```

Then I should get output like this:

```
http://www.website.com/blue/test.html c:\src\blue\test.html        [SAME]
http://www.website.com/green/test2.html c:\src\green\test2.html    [DIFFERENT]
http://www.website.com/red/test3.html c:\src\red\test3.html        [LEFT ONLY]
```

Is there any tool that does this? Or should I write it myself? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've decided to go ahead and create my own utility.

Here's the source:

http://bitbucket.org/jonathanconway/urldiff

Comment: Your link returns a 404